# Global scss variables for Angular components without importing them everytime

Tags: css, angular, sass, global-variables, angular7

I do already have SCSS variables defined in `src/styles/settings/_variables.scss` and I am importing them into `src/styles.scss`, but still these variables aren't available for every single component.

Is there any way to make a global file which holds all SCSS variables for the rest of my components? Because writing `@import` in every single component `.scss` file it is very frustrating, especially if I have many nested components.

I know, there is a lot of similar questions, but it seems like they're all outdated and do not relate to the recent versions of Angular.

I use Angular 7.3 with CLI.

Answer (score 63):

You just need to add a little more config, so where you are declaring your global variables, you need to wrap it up in `:root{}`. So in `src/styles/settings/_variables.scss`.

```
:root {
  --blue: #00b; // or any global you wish to share with components 
}
```

Then when you use them in the SCSS you will need to access them like so.

```
.example-class {
  background-color: var(--blue)
}
```

To add to this regarding comments, this method can use `mixins`, `@media` and `keyframes` and is not limited to just colours /  font. That was an example.

From my understanding you need a global file `src/assets/style/global` and then to import each scss file into there where you are defining them like so.

```
@import 'filename';
```

If you dont want global variables to be used in within a component look when you have the globals working. Look into [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation), as this can be used to ignore them.

Comment: I am using same way but do you know how to use defined variable in css like box-shadow ?

Comment: Yes, native css variables is pretty good already, but this is not only about colors and font-size, but some mixins and functions also.

Comment: try removing the root:{} if you have no luck with the above edit.

Comment: wow this worked.  Where is this in the sass documentation? Wonder what are its implications...

Comment: so if i were to use this variable in my @mixin within the same global scss file wrapped in :root {} how would that work? will this be recognized by all the other components like it recognized the variable?

Comment: This doesn't address the problem. This is using CSS `custom-properties` not SCSS variables.

Answer (score 44):

> Is there any ways to make global file with **scss variables** available for all components?

Without importing global file everytime in each component, you want those **sass variables** been available, it's not possible.

The way it works in **SASS**, if using partials to better organize code, you can apply `@import` directive for referencing. So if there're some sass variables in `shared/_variables.scss`:

```
$lightslategray: #778899;
$darkgray: #A9A9A9;
```

and these variables need to be used in another stylesheet, stylesheet with them must be @import-ed into it firstly:

```
// Shared
@import "shared/variables";

.content {
  background: $lightslategray;
}
```

In Angular it works in a similar way (related referencing external stylesheet). So if you need some `sass variables, mixins or functions` to be used by a particular `component.scss`, there is no other clean way, but to reference them in that `component.scss` using `@import` directive. To ease the task, you can create a file `src/_variables.scss` and use syntax like this in your `component.scss`:

```
@import “~variables.scss”;
```

Answer (score 19):

**Easily possibe to access sass style(s) from a global file** with two steps.

1. Add folder path of the style files to `includePaths` array in `angular.json` file.
2. Import style file by file-name in any component.

let say your files and folder structures is as follows: `src` **>** `my-styles-folder` **>** `var.scss`

`angular.json`

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    ...
    "options": {
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "src/my-styles-folder" // add path only, do not include file name
        ]
      },
      "styles": [
        ...
      ]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

`var.scss`

```
$toolbar-heigh: 70px;
```

`some-component.scss`

```
@import "var"; // var.scss

mat-toolbar {
  height: $toolbar-height;
}
```

Comment: Best solution, Tanx.

Answer (score 12):

step one : go to custom scss file (shared/css/_variable.scss) and write this part

```css
:root{
  --color-text: red;
  --color-btn-success: green;
}
```

after go to style.scss (this is main file) and import this file :

```css
@import './shared/css/Variables';
```

now you can use variables in all components with this Syntax:

```css
.sample{
  color : var(--color-text);
}
```

Comment: you actually dont need to create a separate css file to import by just putting them in your styles.scss/css thus reducing your need to import a separate file into each components scss/css file.

Answer (score 2):

In angular 8 work for me.

In your _variable.scss file you have to add:

```
:root{--my-var:#fabada}
```

After that go in your **angular.json** and add this in **"styles":**

```
{"input":"yourPath/_variables.scss"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each angular component you can use variables from files:

```
@use "/src/styles/settings/variables" as *;
```

after your variables will be available in your component, I hope it's help to you

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `:root{--my-var:#fabada}` in your styles.scss/css and get rid of the extra _variables file.  Then just use `var(--my-var)` in any component.